# Adjusting the Android Text size

Tags: android

I have spent a lot of time to adjust my app's font size but my app still doesn't work properly.

According to the references , devices are divided in 4 groups.`(ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi)`

so the **developers.android** has suggested us to create dimens.xml documents to define different font size for different devices.

I followed the steps to adjust the app's font size,but Surprisingly the ultimate result was incredible. `AVDs` work fine Although the behaviour of real devices is unusual and **unpredictable**.

**definitions**

- res/values-mdpi:35dp
- res/values-hdpi:18dp
- res/values-xhdpi:13dp*

**AVDs VS result:**

- FWVGA-mdpi : Normal
- Nexus S-hdpi : Normal
- Nexus 4-xhdpi : Normal

Real devices VS result

- Lg e445-**mdpi** : unusuall : Extremely Big

If I reduce the size to fix it  , I will have the same problem with samsung. galaxy S4. What should I do ?

```
<dimen name="content_item_txtsize">13dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="content_item_txtsize">18dp</dimen>
<dimen name="content_item_txtsize">35dp</dimen>
```

Comment: You should use `sp` instead of `dp` for font sizes. The will take into account the device's default font configuration, in addition to the size you want the text to be.

Comment: "developers.android has suggested us to create dimens.xml documents to define different font size for different devices" - Could you please post a link to the page which says that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `sp` instead of `dp` for font sizes.
2. Using a single value for all devices should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the screen density modifiers for the values resources.

Instead you can use -w identifier which implies that -smallest width-.

For example you may be want to have bigger text on tablets so you can use values-w820dp folder which states that width of 820 dp or larger screen will use the resources definitions from this folder.

So, in general, slice-up values folder to differentiate phone and tablets.